# google map multiple marker issue in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

i'm working on core php, i have to making google map multiple marker from database i have tried but showing some issue (alert) like :(Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ZERO_RESULTS), i have to passing the value array  ($list) to javascript var data = ; below the my code please check it & help me..

```
<?php
include "db_connection.php";
$locations=array();
    $query =  $conn->query('SELECT `pg_address` FROM `tbl_master_property` limit 10');
     while ($row =$query->fetch_assoc()) {
       $list[] = $row;
    }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Geocoding service</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas 
      {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder;
var map;
var data = <?php echo json_encode($list); ?>; 
//console.log(data);
var pglist = (JSON.stringify(data));
//alert(pglist);
function initialize() 
{
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.3496, -6.3263);
  var mapOptions = 
  {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  codeAddress(pglist);//call the function
}

function codeAddress(address) 
{
  geocoder.geocode( {address:address}, function(results, status) 
  {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
    {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);//center the map over the result
      //place a marker at the location
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
      {
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
   }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is a complete mess... you cannot just pass a bunch of geocodes as a single one geocode and expect it to be working.

Comment: i have checked 'India' single geocode is working sir

Comment: The way I understood from your code is this: in your query, you are getting a list of address with a limit of 10 and storing them in an array $list. Then you used json_encode on list to convert it to json format. After this you used stringify and passed it to variable pglist then passed it to your function codeaddress as the address to be used for geocoding? Did you even try to check what your "address" looks like? Fix your code first. Use for loop or foreach to geocode each address in your array one by one.

Comment: Hi  tomjosef, i have done your way but now showing issue for (Geocode was not successful for the following reason: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT),

Comment: for loop :  for (var i = 0; i < pglist.length; i++) {
  geocoder.geocode( {address:pglist[i]}, function(results, status) 
  {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
    {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);//center the map over the result
      //place a marker at the location
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
      {
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
   }
  });
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than passing an object directly into your `codeAddress` function pass each individual address in a loop - though if there are lots of items in the source data you could easily exceed your daily quota.

Initially you define `$locations=array();` but then attempt to populate what appears to be an undeclared array `$list` - presumably you intend to populate `$locations`?

```
<?php
    include "db_connection.php";

    $locations = array();
    $query =  $conn->query('SELECT `pg_address` FROM `tbl_master_property` limit 10');
    while( $row=$query->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $locations[] = $row['pg_address'];
    }
?>
<html>
  <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Geocoding service</title>
        <style>
          html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
          }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var geocoder;
            var map;
            var data = <?php echo json_encode( $locations ); ?>;

            function initialize(){
              geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
              var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.3496, -6.3263);
              var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng
              }
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

              for( var n in data ){
                codeAddress.call( this, data[ n ] );
              }
            }

            function codeAddress(address) {
              geocoder.geocode( {address:address}, function(results, status) {
                if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {

                  map.setCenter( results[0].geometry.location );

                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map,
                      position: results[0].geometry.location
                  });

                } else {
                  alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
               }
              });
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', initialize );

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi RamRaider thank you for your reply, i executed you code but it is showing like (Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ZERO_RESULTS) please check it sir

Comment: not showing marker sir

Comment: Hi RamRaider thank you  it is working fine but limited address only showing i need more address will populate map

Comment: Hi @Lamp. Depending upon the data in your db you may or may not find that changing `$locations[] = $row['pg_address'];` to `$locations[] = urldecode( $row['pg_address'] );` gives more success. If though after that there is not change then perhaps look at the data and try manually querying google on a particular address that you know fails